# Why would PHP date() function give inconsistent times? Off by 2 hours out of the blue

Tags: php, datetime

I have a page where I get a date/time to insert into a MySQL database.

The timezone the server in is two hours ahead.

In my php.ini I have `date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles`

I noticed sometimes the time was off by two hours.

MySQL field is type datetime, not null (and I just notice I haven't set default value)

I'm using Codeigniter, if that matters.

This is how I get the time to insert into the database:

`$newData['time'] = $time = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");`

I inserted a line of code after that to write the time to the error log.

`log_message('error', "Date time is $time");`

Why is the time changing like this?  This portion of the log is from 2:00pm to 2:30pm local time.

This is all coming from a single page on my site in the span of 29 minutes.

```
110 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:00:57 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:00:57
111 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:01:38 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:01:38
112 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:01:57 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:01:57
113 ERROR - 2011-12-20 16:02:19 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 16:02:19
114 ERROR - 2011-12-20 16:02:28 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 16:02:28
115 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:03:26 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:03:26
116 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:03:32 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:03:32
117 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:03:46 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:03:46
118 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:04:43 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:04:43
119 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:04:53 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:04:53
120 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:04:58 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:04:58
121 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:05:03 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:05:03
122 ERROR - 2011-12-20 16:07:05 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 16:07:05
123 ERROR - 2011-12-20 16:07:25 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 16:07:25
124 ERROR - 2011-12-20 16:07:54 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 16:07:54
125 ERROR - 2011-12-20 16:08:05 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 16:08:05
126 ERROR - 2011-12-20 16:08:15 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 16:08:15
127 ERROR - 2011-12-20 16:09:04 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 16:09:04
128 ERROR - 2011-12-20 16:09:14 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 16:09:14
129 ERROR - 2011-12-20 16:09:44 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 16:09:44
130 ERROR - 2011-12-20 16:10:08 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 16:10:08
131 ERROR - 2011-12-20 16:10:27 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 16:10:27
132 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:12:16 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:12:16
133 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:15:30 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:15:30
134 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:16:20 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:16:20
135 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:17:55 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:17:55
136 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:18:51 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:18:51
137 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:19:16 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:19:16
138 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:20:08 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:20:08
139 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:27:29 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:27:29
140 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:29:31 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:29:31
141 ERROR - 2011-12-20 14:29:55 --> Date time is 2011-12-20 14:29:55
```

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: The error times are consistent with the times you are logging. Try $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] to see what time your web server thinks it is or `\`date\`` to see what time your system thinks it is (UNIX/Linux)

Comment: in your config file for code igniter is there a contradictory timezone set under time_reference?

Comment: change your date format to something more verbose. also log gmdate(). I suspect your timezone changed. the TZ environment variable can change php's timezone, and environment variables are easily changed from outside of php. Maybe, a webserver process/thread is "dirty" and so pollute your php scripts.

Comment: Daylight saving? I might be wrong but I'm sure America is two hours closer to GMT (stated as an example) for a week at the start of November.

Comment: Could you dump the output of time() too? It might as well be the server itself is faulty, that is, the time actually changes (not the TZ)

Comment: @SOliver: daylight savings is only _one_ hour and it fell back (away from GMT). For example, EDT to EST went from UTC-0400 to UTC-0500 when daylight savings ended at 2 a.m. on November 6, 2011.

Comment: Great answer from Hostgator (landed there after running away screaming from GoDaddy)

`Hello,

It would appear that at times your script is using the timezone you have configured "America/Los_Angeles" and sometimes it is using the servers localtime, "America/Chicago". Without looking through the script itself, it's difficult to say way, but it would appear to be a bug.

Please don't hesitate to let us know if you have any other questions.`

Not that I expected much help from their tech support anyway.  

CI config is set to use 'local' as opposed to 'gmt'.

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be an issue with your system time itself like meouw said, or as John B mentioned, the PHP timezone might be getting overwritten somewhere in your CI config.

Assuming you're running a linux/gnu box, you should change your error logging to something like this:

`log_message('error', "PHP time is $time, System time is ".exec('date'));`

Which should at least let you know if the issue is with your system time or PHP's time

(Note: You're looking for the system time jumping hours apart like your PHP time does, system time being a second or two different from your PHP time is normal)

Comment: Hasn't happened again yet.  I changed the error logging to include both times.  Great idea, thanks.  Both times are correct and indicate the proper time zone.  Waiting for a response from the hosting company.  Maybe it was just a hiccup on their end.
Codeigniter config is set to 'local' as opposed to 'gmt'.

Thanks for the quick suggestions!